# Xcode 11, Cocos2dx compilation problem: Argument value 10880 is outside the valid range [0, 255] btVector3.h

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-x, ios13, xcode11

Please see attach image. In Xcode 11, Cocos2d-x giving error : Argument value 10880 is outside the valid range [0, 255] btVector3.h

Error coming for code line

```
y = bt_splat_ps(y, 0x80); // in file btVector3.h
```

[image]
How to solve this ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Temporary solution suggested in this forum : https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/xcode-11-ios-13-cocos-not-running/46825

In btVector3.h, just replace

```
#define BT_SHUFFLE(x,y,z,w) ((w)<<6 | (z)<<4 | (y)<<2 | (x))
```

With new code:

```
#define BT_SHUFFLE(x, y, z, w) (((w) << 6 | (z) << 4 | (y) << 2 | (x)) & 0xff)
```

This solves compilation error. Waiting for Valid Fix from Cocos2d Team :-